# "Decline and delete" option in waffle bar does not show that comment is deleted until you refresh the page

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, comment-flags, waffle-bar

♦ moderators have a so-called 'waffle bar' to handle flags on Q&A pages:

[image]

This includes two options to delete a flagged comment: a simple "delete" and (hidden behind the dots) "decline and delete". The difference is that the former marks the comment flag as helpful, which may not be desirable if it's an "unfriendly" or "rude" flag. Clicking "delete" will immediately delete the comment (you don't need to refresh the page); clicking "decline and delete" closes the waffle bar (if there are no other flags) but does not show that the comment is deleted, which is kind of confusing; you have to refresh the page to see that it is actually deleted:

[image]